# Can't install gnome extensions, fresh 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

When open extensions.gnome.org and open any extension, I can press button on/off. It switches but nothing happens, no message about installation pop up. Previously, a year ago, on other machines with 20.04, everything was fine.

P.S. I install gnome-extensions, chrome-gnome-extensions, gnome-tweaks. Tried chrome and firefox and install required extensions and them.

P.P.S. It turns out that extensions can be installed manually quite easy: https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/

Comment: did u find any fix

Answer (score -1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (this opens GNOME panel). Enter `r` in the prompt (to restart GNOME) and press `Enter`.

Try to press ON on the website, this should work now and install the extension.

#### Explanation (my guess)

The UI (loaded in memory) doesn't respond to updates (on disk). It needs a kick. Restarting is a "kick".

Comment: Please explain what `r` does.  Giving resolving advice is just the beginning of a good answer.  Please always explain your advice with the intent to educate/empower the asker and thousands of future researchers.